# Relation in Linq Generating an error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

i have a table EmpInf
field

```
EmpId
EmpName
Salary
DeptNumber
```

and Dept
Field

```
DeptNo
DeptName
```

a relation

```
Dept.DeptNo= EmpInf.DeptNumber
```

while creating a linq query to extract a EmpName And a dept in which it work
i tried to write Linq as follows

```
var obj1 = from c in obj.EmpInfs join
                    d in obj.Dept1 on c.DeptNumber equals d.DeptNo into s
                   where c.EmpName == "m"
                   select new { EmpName=c.EmpName, DeptName=s};

        GridView1.DataSource = obj1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

and tried this also

```
 var obj1 = from c in obj.EmpInfs 
                   from d in obj.Dept1
                   where c.EmpName == "m"
                   select new { EmpName=c.EmpName, DeptName=d.DeptName};

        GridView1.DataSource = obj1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

in both the codes it is not giving the desire output. thanks for assistence

Comment: What is the result? What do you expect?

Comment: The EmpName and the department in which it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj1 = from c in obj.EmpInfs join
                   d in obj.Dept1 on c.DeptNumber equals d.DeptNo
                   where c.EmpName == "m"
                   select new { EmpName=c.EmpName, DeptName=d.DeptName};
```

The problem with the first attempt is that "s" is an object of type "Dept" and not the department name. The problem with the second attempt is that it is making a cross join,